# Is there a way to pipe the output of :nmap to a file in vim?

Tags: vim

When I type `:nmap<cr>` in normal mode, I just get a scrollable buffer of all the keymappings. I'd like to save this to a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`:redir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3aredir):

```
:redir > nmap.txt
:silent nmap
:redir END
```

Then `nmap.txt` will contain the output of `:nmap`.

Comment: Use `silent nmap` or `set nomore` before the whole block. In this case you won’t have to tap through the pages (in the first case nothing will be shown, but nmap.txt still won’t be empty. In the second it will just show some last lines).

Comment: @ZyX Don't know why I didn't think of `silent`… updated, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Any way to do this in a single line?